# Trouble pasting in the "save-as" window in snap apps

Tags: firefox, snap, chromium, 22.04, telegram

Since I upgraded to ubuntu 22.04, when trying to paste in the "save-as" window in snap apps (Firefox, Chromium, Telegram), I get the message "the folder contents could not be displayed" and "operation not supported". I wonder if there is something wrong with my set-up, or whether this might a bug that I should report.
[image: screenshot of message]

Comment: Assuming you were just trying to paste text, you might try parcellite which is a clipboard manager and see if that works better.

Comment: I can reproduce this perfectly. This is yet other undesired behaviour of the snap (and flatpak) versions, likely related to xdg-portal. You did not even mention that the second time you try this, the dialog is not in focus. You have to focus it first before you even can start pasting. Worthy filing as an issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is buggy behavior. Of course, one should be able to paste a string in the name field of a file dialog.

Reported as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1972984